# How to Choose more than one item in method in java

Tags: java

I have just created a senario that looping which was I have to choose columns what I have selected from data base like this javaMain which have the senario

```
package myrestorderproject;

import enitities.Menu;
import enitities.Tables;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
public class MyRestOrderProject {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*-*-*-*-*-*Welcome to MyRestaurant*-*-*-*-*-*\n");
        System.out.println("Please Choose Table From Tables List");
        Tables t = new Tables();
        t.getAllRows();
        ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean orderNotFinished = true;

        while (orderNotFinished) {

            System.out.print("Enter Table Number: ");
            String tableNumber = input.nextLine();

            boolean insertedTableNumber = db.goTodataBase.checkTableNumber(tableNumber);
            if (insertedTableNumber) {
                System.out.println("You Choose Table Number: " + tableNumber);
                Menu m = new Menu();
                m.getAllRows();
                while (orderNotFinished) {

                    System.out.println("Please Choose Item From Menu List");

                    input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String itemChosen = input.nextLine();
                    boolean insertedMenuItemId = db.goTodataBase.checkMenuItemInDB(itemChosen);
                    if (insertedMenuItemId) {
                        System.out.println("You Choose Item ID: " + itemChosen);
                        listItem.add(m.getAllRows(itemChosen));
                        System.out.print("Do you need to add more Items ? ");
                        String hasFinished = input.nextLine();
                        orderNotFinished = hasFinished.equals("yes");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Item Chosen doen't exist");
                    }

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Table number does not exist");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I need now in the part which print "Please Choose Item From Menu List" after I choose the right Item Close the while loop,and I need also to choose more than one item that if I choose Items from menu give me the items was chosen with details getting from menu table
Like If I Choose Item ID 1 +Item ID 2 + Item ID 3 says that you have chosen 
Item 1 Vegetable Pakora 20.00 veg Starters
Item 1 Vegetable Pakora 20.00 veg Starters
Item 1 Chicken Tikka 20.00 Non-veg Starters
after that exit the while loop

as every column have an ID, name, price, type and Category
and this method that am using in previous senario

```
public static boolean checkMenuItemInDB(String menuId) {
    try {
        setConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String strCheck = "select * from menu where "
                + "Menu_Id=" + menuId;
        stmt.executeQuery(strCheck);
        while (stmt.getResultSet().next()) {                
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is menu Class

```
package enitities;

import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
public class Menu {
    private int Menu_Id;
    private String Name;
    private float Price;
    private String Type;
    private String Category;

    public int getMenu_Id() {
        return Menu_Id;
    }

    public void setMenu_Id(int Menu_Id) {
        this.Menu_Id = Menu_Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float Price) {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String Type) {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String Category) {
        this.Category = Category;
    }
        public void getAllRows() {
        db.goTodataBase.printData("menu");
    }

        public String getAllRows(String itemChosen) {
        db.goTodataBase.printData("menu");
        return itemChosen;
    }
}
```

this is a method which I calls in getAllRows

```
    public static void printData(String tableNameOrSelectStatement) {
        try {
            setConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            String strSelectPart = tableNameOrSelectStatement.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase();
            String strSelect;
            if ("select ".equals(strSelectPart)) {
                strSelect = tableNameOrSelectStatement;
            } else {
                strSelect = "select * from " + tableNameOrSelectStatement;
            }
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int c = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
                    if (i > 1) {
                        System.out.print(",  ");
                    }
                    String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
//                    System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    System.out.print(columnValue + " ");

                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Tools.msgBox(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you need to return multiple items you should use a collection class of some sort, an ArrayList for example.

Comment: By the way: you are swallowing exceptions, you shoud not do that.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson aha you mean that instead of return boolean return ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the loop :**

Programmer tips : You need to avoid as much as possible `while(true)`-loop.

In your case you could use a system of flag, it will look like :

```
boolean customerHasFinished = false;
while(!customerHasFinished){
    ...
    //Do your stuff
    ...

    System.out.print("Have you finished ? ");
    String hasFinished = input.nextLine();
    customerHasFinished = hasFinished.equals("yes");
}
```

**About multiple items :**

The best way to store multiple items is to use [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

In your case, you will probably need to create a Java class that represent an Item. Having fields like name, cost, etc. And then create a collection of Item.

An example with an ArrayList :

```
List<Item> listItem = new ArrayList<Item>();
boolean orderNotFinished = true;
while (orderNotFinished) {
    System.out.println("Please Choose an Item From Menu List");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemChosen = input.nextLine();
    boolean insertedMenuItemId = db.goTodataBase.checkMenuItemInDB(itemChosen);
    if (insertedMenuItemId) {
        System.out.println("You Choose Item ID: " + itemChosen);
        listItem.add(Item.getItemByName(itemChosen)); //Add the chosen item to the list
        System.out.print("You want something else ? ");
        String hasFinished = input.nextLine();
        orderNotFinished = hasFinished.equals("yes");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Item Chosen doen't exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t do string comparison with ==. Use the equals method.

Comment: how about return multiple items?

Comment: @vincrichaud for Java Class Item I created like this class called menu have all items attributes I have a method that getAllRows In the menu table but I overloaded it by adding String parameter by return String value for the item chosen I tried to add this overloaded method but it gives me underlined error "no suitable method found for add(String)" how can I solve this please?

Comment: @vincrichaud should I have to add a construtor in menu.java??

Comment: @H.Dev If you store your item as String (and not as an Item object) you should create a list of String and not a List of Item. This explain the error your are getting.

Comment: @vincrichaud it works but It shows me all Items in the menu not the items what I was Choose please could you check my edits, I edited my post

Comment: @H.Dev when you call `getAllrows()` it shows you all the items cause it's what you ass him to do. And that's correct regarding to your first main cause you want to display all the avilable items to customer. But In my answer the list `listItem` should contain only the chosen ones

Comment: @vincrichaud that actually I did I suppose that i called list item and calls the getAllRows method and then put between the () itemChosen from getAllRows I thought that it will works as I want :D, I mean I need to filter getAllRows as to give me the ItemChosen